# Chrome Extension: Pass Input Element value from main container to another script file for it to use

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Pretty new to extensions, but I have an HTML file which is the main drop-down container when you click the icon in the browser. In here I have 2 input elements, I need to pass the value of the input elements to another script which is being injected via the code below. Contentscript.js actually adds another script tag, Let's call it Script A, to the document object. Script A creates its own object and the input elements from the page have values that modify this object, hence why I need those values propagated down.

Is there a way to do this?

```
function click(e) {

  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:"contentscript.js"});

  window.close();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var d = document.getElementById("Modify");//a button on the container to execute the script

  d.addEventListener('click',click);

});
```

Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would write your content script to simply define a function, call it "content_script_func", which takes an argument input_data.

Now from your popup page, call chrome.tabs.executeScript with a "code" parameter with the value

`"(" + content_script_func.toString() + ")(" + JSON.stringify( {input1:"val1", input2: "val2" } ) + ")"`

Now your content script has all the data it needs to insert everything into the page's DOM.

Comment: I'm confused. If I do it as you say, what's in content_script_func, is it supposed to be defined already? Where would I define this new function which takes a json object {input1:"val1", input2: "val2" } as a parameter? Do execute this line after the one I wrote or is this method instead of that one? Thanks!

Comment: Also is JSON.stringify available by default?

Comment: Hi. To clarify, I would define your "content_script_function" in your background page. And your background page would serialize it using .toString(). "content_script_function" would essentially contain anything you need to do on the content script page, and you're able to pass in the arguments to that function easily by calling JSON.stringify. And yes, JSON.stringify is always available in chrome.